# How do I get my code to run in a cloud environment?

Tags: c, cloud

I want to realize the goal that the code can run in a cloud environment,but I have no idea how to build a cloud environment.So I hope you could show me the steps that how to build a cloud environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your code on the cloud, Go to the AWS console, create an EC2 instance, and run your code.